# C - print function not printing?

Tags: c, string, struct

I'm trying to print a string value for one of my structs but it is printing out nothing, even though it compiles. Was wondering if someone can help me point out where I went wrong with my function.

```
typedef struct {
    char        firstName[MAX_STR];
    char        lastName[MAX_STR];
    int         numVehicles;
    VehicleType cars[MAX_VEHICLES];
} CustomerType;

void print_customer(CustomerType *c) {
    printf("%s %s, \n", c->firstName, c->lastName);
}

CustomerType create_customer(char* fname, char* lname) {
    CustomerType customer;
    strcpy(customer.firstName, fname);
    strcpy(customer.lastName, lname);
}

int main() {
    CustomerType customers[MAX_CUSTOMERS];
    customers[0] = create_customer("John", "Bob");
    print_customer(&customers[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I think my problem is that I'm not calling the string value correctly in my print function.

Comment: `create_customer` doesn't return, which results in undefined behavior from there on. Turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: @deidei Thanks! that was it.

Comment: when posting about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can easily reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning customer.

```
CustomerType create_customer(char* fname, char* lname) {
    CustomerType customer;
    strcpy(customer.firstName, fname);
    strcpy(customer.lastName, lname);
    return customer; 
}
```

Comment: You must allocate a new customer, this is returning the customer which is in stack and will not be valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the customer from the function `create_customer`. Nonetheless, you must allocate the customer dynamically. Besides that, I also encourage you to check the string sizes before you copy them, otherwise a overflow may happen. Here is the code:

```
CustomerType create_customer(char* fname, char* lname) {
    /* allocate a new customer */
    CustomerType *c = malloc(sizeof(CustomerType)); /

    /* ensure the string size before copying it */
    int size_str_to_copy = (strlen(fname) >= MAX_STR) ? MAX_STR : strlen(fname);
    /* copy the string with the safe size */
    strncpy(c->firstName, fname, size_str_to_copy);

    /* ensure the string size before copying it */
    size_str_to_copy = (strlen(lname) >= MAX_STR) ? MAX_STR : strlen(lname);
    /* copy the string with the safe size */
    strncpy(c->lastName, lname, size_str_to_copy);

    /* return the allocated customer pointer */
    return customer; 
}
```

Also, don't forget to free the created customers.